# Python - Returning variable from function trouble

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm currently learning Python and am creating a maths quiz.

I have created a function that loops, first creating a random maths sum, asks for the answer and then compares the input to the actual answer; if a question is wrong the player loses a point - vice versa. At the end a score is calculated, this is what I'm trying to return at the end of the function and print in the main.py file where I receive a NameError 'score' is not defined.

I have racked my head on trying to figure this out. Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
#generateQuestion.py

    `def generate(lives, maxNum):
        import random
        score= 0
        questionNumber = 1

        while questionNumber <=10:

                try:
                    ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/'] 
                    num1 = random.randint(0,(maxNum))
                    num2 = random.randint(0,10)
                    operation = random.choice(ops)
                    question = (str(num1) + operation + str(num2))


                    print ('Question', questionNumber)
                    print (question)
                    maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))
                    answer=float(input("What is the answer? "))

                except ValueError:
                    print ('Please enter a number.')
                    continue

                if answer == maths:
                    print ('Correct')
                    score = score + 1
                    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
                    print ('Score:', score)
                    print ('Lives:', lives)
                    print('\n')
                    continue

                elif lives == 1:
                    print ('You died!')
                    print('\n')
                    break

                else:
                    print ('Wrong answer. The answer was actually', maths)
                    lives = lives - 1
                    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
                    print ('Score:', score)
                    print ('Lives:', lives)
                    print('\n')
                    continue

        if questionNumber == 0:
            print ('All done!')
            return score       
        `
```

My main file

```
#main.py
        import random
        from generateQuestion import generate


        #Welcome message and name input.
        print ('Welcome, yes! This is maths!')
        name = input("What is your name: ")
        print("Hello there",name,"!" )
        print('\n')

        #difficulty prompt
        while True:

        #if input is not 1, 2 or 3, re-prompts.
            try:
                difficulty = int (input(' Enter difficulty (1. Easy, 2. Medium, 3. Hard): '))       
            except ValueError:
                print ('Please enter a number between 1 to 3.')
                continue
            if difficulty < 4:
                break
            else:
                print ('Between 1-3 please.')

        #if correct number is inputted (1, 2 or 3).
        if difficulty == 1:
            print ('You chose Easy')
            lives = int(3)
            maxNum = int(10)


        if difficulty == 2:
            print ('You chose Medium')
            lives = int(2)
            maxNum = int(25)


        if difficulty == 3:
            print ('You chose Hard')
            lives = int(1)
            maxNum = int(50)

        print ('You have a life count of', lives)
        print('\n')

        #generateQuestion
        print ('Please answer: ')
        generate(lives, maxNum)

        print (score) 
        #not printing^^

        '
```

I have tried a different method just using the function files (without the main) and have narrowed it down to the problem being the returning of the score variable, this code is:

```
def generate(lives, maxNum):
    import random
    questionNumber = 1
    score= 0
    lives= 0
    maxNum= 10

    #evalualates question to find answer (maths = answer)
    while questionNumber <=10:

            try:
                ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/'] 
                num1 = random.randint(0,(maxNum))
                num2 = random.randint(0,10)
                operation = random.choice(ops)
                question = (str(num1) + operation + str(num2))


                print ('Question', questionNumber)
                print (question)
                maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))
                answer=float(input("What is the answer? "))

            except ValueError:
                print ('Please enter a number.')
                continue

            if answer == maths:
                print ('Correct')
                score = score + 1
                questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
                print ('Score:', score)
                print ('Lives:', lives)
                print('\n')
                continue

            elif lives == 1:
                print ('You died!')
                print('\n')
                break

            else:
                print ('Wrong answer. The answer was actually', maths)
                lives = lives - 1
                questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
                print ('Score:', score)
                print ('Lives:', lives)
                print('\n')
                continue

    if questionNumber == 0:
        return score


def scoreCount():
    generate(score)
    print (score)


scoreCount()
```

Comment: Copy-paste the *full* traceback into your question ([edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29535095/edit)); the traceback often shows where and what went wrong, if you carefully read it.

Comment: The traceback is as follows: >>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):

generateQuestion.py", line 56, in scoreCount
    generate(score)
NameError: name 'score' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @Youngn: your generate method accepts 2 arguments and you are passing only one variable. You are sending the variable score which is neither created nor initialized. Again you are not receiving the returned variable. Before trying something please make sure that you know basic concepts and syntaxes of language.

Comment: Just as Chiyaan says above: you call `generate` with just one variable (that is not even defined yet), like `generate(score)`. Yet you have defined the function to accept two variables, `lives` and `maxNum`; that is incompatible. You may want to read up in the [tutorial on functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with these last lines in main:

```
print ('Please answer: ')
generate(lives, maxNum)
print ('score')
```

You are not receiving the returned value. It should be changed to:

```
print ('Please answer: ')
score = generate(lives, maxNum) #not generate(lives, maxNum)
print (score)  # not print('score')
```

This will work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just tried this, no change. Same NameError occurring.

Comment: @Youngn' Please copy and paste the actual error message including the traceback.

Comment: @youngn as per the update u did to the program.. seems u just changed the last line print (score) please do change the line generate(lives, maxNum) as score = generate(lives, maxNum). then it will work

Comment: So I have changed both now and am receiving this message: 
main.py", line 52, in <module>
    score = generate(lives, maxNum)
TypeError: generate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score'
>>>

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is not:

```
def a():
    score = 3
    return score
def b():
    a()
    print(score)
```

(And `print('score')` will simply print the word `'score'`.)

It works like this:

```
def a():
    score = 3
    return score

def b():
    print(a())
```